# How to take off an URL from this string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, image, url

I got this string coming from an API: (I'm coding in javascript)

```
"{\"profile\":{\"profile_image\":\"http://image.avatar.com/fichiers/2017/22/1496503336-avatar.png\",\"name\":\"ejeje\"}}"
```

How can I get the image URL `http://image.avatar.com/fichiers/2017/22/1496503336-avatar.png\` ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: `var o = JSON.parse(str); alert(o.profile.profile_image);`

Comment: This is JSON data. Use the appropriate tool (a JSON parser), not regex.